# excel VBA only keep the certain part of a the text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that is imported into excel every day, and the last column of information "Z", is all of the comments that have been left by previous agents working on the account. I am only interested in the last comment, but it can be of any length, so i cant just grab x amount of characters.

**Question:** Is there a way to only pull the last comment based on the criteria of the comment? (every comment ends with the username, date, and time-stamp:

Example of a cell:

```
Example of agent1 comment. [USERNAME1-xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx PM] - Example of agent2 comment. [USERNAME2-xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx PM])
```

In this scenario, the only text that i would want in the cell would be: "Example of agent2 comment.".

For the record, all of the imported report starts on "A2".

Comment: What have you tried? Pull the comment out, then use a mix of `MID()` and `SEARCH()`, should get you started.

Comment: the problem is that there is about 300 rows of info each with about 20 different comments. is there a way to select the second to last set of brackets"[]" and pull all the info after? I dont know how to do this if it is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I shouldn't do this as you haven't shown what you've tried yet, but this code should do the trick.

Enter in a cell:  `=ExtractLastComment(H3)` where H3 contains the comment.

```
'Use this procedure to run on a range of cells.
'The result is placed one cell to the right of the comment: "Offset(, 1)"
Public Sub CommentsInColumn()

    Dim rTarget As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Set rTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A30")

    For Each rCell In rTarget
        rCell.Offset(, 1) = ExtractLastComment(rCell)
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Function ExtractLastComment(Target As Range) As Variant

    Dim sCommentText As String

    If HasComment(Target) Then
        'Get the comment text.
        sCommentText = Target.Comment.Text

        If InStrRev(sCommentText, "[") <> 0 Then
            'Find the last open bracket and take everything to the left of it.
            sCommentText = Trim(Left(sCommentText, InStrRev(sCommentText, "[") - 1))

            'Any closing brackets left?
            If InStrRev(sCommentText, "]") <> 0 Then
                'Take everything from last closing bracket to end of text.
                sCommentText = Mid(sCommentText, InStrRev(sCommentText, "]") + 4)
            End If
            ExtractLastComment = sCommentText
        Else
             ExtractLastComment = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If

    Else
        'There isn't a comment in the cell, return a !#NULL error.
        ExtractLastComment = CVErr(xlErrNull)
    End If

End Function


Public Function HasComment(Target As Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        With Target
            HasComment = Not .Comment Is Nothing
        End With
    Else
        Err.Raise 513, "HasComment()", "Argument must reference single cell."
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure HasComment."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, How would I save this as a macro to run over the entire "Z" Column, instead of as a function?

Comment: You could either enter the formula in one cell and drag down, or I've added a procedure at the top of the code to show how to run it over a range of cells.  Have also updated the main code to account for when a bracket isn't in the comment ( will show #VALUE! error).

Comment: after changing the line of code: "Set rTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A30")" to Set rTarget = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("z2", ActiveSheet.Range("z2").End(xlDown)). as all of my comments are in the "Z" column, it returns #NULL!, as if there is no txt in the Z column.

Comment: That'll be the line following the `'There isn't a comment in the cell, return a !#NULL error.` comment.  What do you want it to say if there's no comment in the cell?  There's no need to say `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` - the ActiveSheet will always be in the ActiveWorkbook - you can just use `ActiveSheet` (as you have within the brackets).

Comment: thanks for the active sheet info, but what im saying is that it is saying there is no info in any of the cells in the z column.

Example text in column Z: [SR Activities] - Fax - Outbound - sent to agent for additional location - [APULVER-05/15/2017 12:30:32 PM] - [SR Activities] - Emailed Business - unable to open Wf for Motorsports - email AM for coverage approval - [APULVER-05/16/2017 01:01:38 PM]

I would like it to return: Emailed Business - unable to open Wf for Motorsports - email AM for coverage approval - [APULVER-05/16/2017 01:01:38 PM]
 but it says #NULL!

Comment: It returns **Emailed Business - unable to open Wf for Motorsports - email AM for coverage approval -** in AA2 for me with **[SR Activities] - Fax - Outbound - sent to agent for additional location - [APULVER-05/15/2017 12:30:32 PM] - [SR Activities] - Emailed Business - unable to open Wf for Motorsports - email AM for coverage approval - [APULVER-05/16/2017 01:01:38 PM]** entered as a comment in cell Z2.  The text is in a comment isn't it?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, it is not an "excel comment", it is a comment put into our site, and when the report runs, all of site's comments are pulled into 1 string and placed in the "Z" column. 

At that point i want to pull the last "site comment" out of the string of text, that is in the actual cell.

Comment: Change  `sCommentText = Target.Comment.Text` to `sCommentText = Target.Value` and it'll probably work.